# How to obtain the real projective space by attaching handles

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Kosinski's Differentiable Manifolds and on section VI-7 on the cancellation lemma, there is an exercise at the end to show that $$\mathbb{RP}^m =D^m \cup H^1 \cup ... \cup H^m$$
I tried checking it for $m=2$ and my problem is that if you attach a 1-handle to a $D^2$ you get something like a cylinder, so if you attach the next 2-handle you will just close one of the sides and get $D^2$ back.
What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> I don't know the details of Kosinski's book, but the usual picture is, attaching a $1$-handle to a point gives a circle, and attaching a disk (wrapping the boundary of the disk _twice_ around the circle) gives a projective plane.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang , I think to attach handles, unlike for CW complexes, the attaching sphere should be embedded in the manifold, so you cannot attach a 1-handle to a point and you can't wrap twice the boundary of the disk along the circle, since it wont be injective and thus not an embedding.

Comment: Another guess: The 1-handle is viewed as a thin rectangular strip, and is glued to the boundary of the initial 2-disk with a half-twist, yielding (a surface homeomorphic to) a Moebius strip. The disk is attached to the Moebius strip by gluing along the boundary in the conventional way. <> If there are details about the attaching (especially, are we free to make choices about how we attach handles?), that might be good to edit into the question body.